# Concrete5 (application/config/doctrine/proxies\__CG__ConcreteCoreEntitySiteType.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: concrete5, concrete5-8.x

When installing concrete5-8.3.2 locally, after installation it shows me this error message:

```
 require(C:/xampp/htdocs/concrete5/application/config/doctrine/proxies\__CG__ConcreteCoreEntitySiteType.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

The proxies directory is empty.
I don't know how to solve this.
I haved found an answer but doesn't work for me
"Go to /dashboard/system/environment/entities and click on the red "refresh entities" button".
Update: I haved install concrete5-6.3.5 locally it works perfectly but version concrete5-8.3.2 dosen't work and i don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

Did you download Concrete5 from Concrete5.org or from Github? Normally if you downloaded it from Concrete5.org this should not happen.